# magento 2 how to secure Cookie mage-cache-sessid and enable Secured Flag

Tags: security, cookie, https

Here Am trying to enable HttpOnly and Secured Flag for Cookies `mage-cache-sessid` or my domain. I did configuration in ***admin Panel >> store >> configuration >> general >> web*** [image]

but still flags not enabled for domain and Cookies.
Can I get help? Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you flush the Magento cache and also the browser cache?

Comment: thank you Anna Volkl for replying , I executed following commands after Clearing browser Cache,
`php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento cache:clean
php bin/magento cache:flush`

I opened in incognito mode still not Cookie set as secured